# Using a wildcard in gradle copy task

Tags: gradle

I'd like to copy a directory using a wildcard, however the `from` method of the Gradle `copy` task doesn't accept a wildcard.

```gradle
// this doesn't work
task copyDirectory(type: Copy) {
        from "/path/to/folder-*/"
        into "/target"
}
// this does
task copyDirectory(type: Copy) {
        from "/path/to/folder-1.0/"
        into "/target"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use 'include' task property to specify exact files ot directories you need to copy, something like this:

```gradle
task copyDirectory(type: Copy) {
    from "/path/to/"
    include 'test-*/'
    into "/target"
}
```

**Update:** if you want to copy only directories content, then you have to deal with every file separately, something like this:

```gradle
task copyDirectory(type: Copy) {
    from "/path/to/"
    include 'test-*/'
    into "/target"
    eachFile {
        def segments = it.getRelativePath().getSegments() as List
        it.setPath(segments.tail().join("/"))
        return it
    }
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

Comment: That creates the output folder target/test-*, I need the contents of test-* copied directly into target

Comment: You have to specify such a things in your question. Ok, just updated an answer, to remove the root directories while copying.